# c# TransactionScope didnt roll back

Tags: c#, file, rollback, transactionscope

I'm new in C# and trying out how TransactionScope work. Here is my code, and i wonder why my Transaction didn't roll back:

```
string file1 = "txf1.txt";
string file2 = "txf2.txt";
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(file1))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
}

using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(file2))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
}

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    File.AppendAllText(file1, "Transaktion");
    scope.Complete();
}

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    File.AppendAllText(file2, "Transaktion");
    //should roll back the file, but doesn't
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a transaction manager in `File`, it is not a "software transaction". Almost 100% of time `TransactionScope` will be used in conjunction with ADO.NET or libraries built on top of it such as Entity Framework or Dapper. See more at MSDN [TransactionScope Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).